# For sorting 10^9 unique 9-digit numbers, would radix sort or counting sort be faster, and why?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, radix-sort

> For sorting $10^9$ unique 9-digit numbers, would radix sort or counting sort be faster, and why?

I know that radix sort is $O(nk)$ and counting sort is $O(n+k)$, but can’t understand how to apply this.

Comment: Why not program both and see which one is faster in practice?

Comment: As far as natural numbers representable with nine decimal digits are concerned, a question about $10^9$ unique ones looks a trick question even allowing leading zeroes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We can fill in the numbers for both:

#### Radix Sort

The complexity of radix sort is $O(nk)$ with $k$ being the size of the numbers. Therefore we get approximately $9 \cdot 10^9 = 9.000.000.000$ iterations for Radix sort.

#### Count Sort

The complexity of radix sort is $O(n+k)$ with $k$ being the range of the numbers. In the worst case the range is $10^{9} -1$. So we get approximately  $10^{9}-1 + 10^9 = 2.000.000.000$ iterations  for count sort.

So count sort would be faster.

Comment: Except it depends on the constant factor hidden by Landau notation...

Comment: Thank you so much. This matched the solution and the reasoning helps me understand how to apply the complexity function.

Comment: You should note that orlp is right and this is not the exact number of operations, but it approximates a factor which is multiplied by the number of operations in each function. I edited my answer to state it more correctly

Answer (score 1):

There are exactly 10^9 unique nine digit numbers, so the sorted array is just 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 999,999,999.